# R: Storing data within a function and retrieving without using "return"

Tags: r

The following simple example will help me address a problem in my program implementation.

```
fun2<-function(j)
{
x<-rnorm(10)
y<-runif(10)
Sum<-sum(x,y)
Prod<-prod(x,y)
return(Sum)
}
j=1:10
Try<-lapply(j,fun2)
```

#

I want to store "Prod" at each iteration so I can access it after running the function fun2. I tried using assign() to create space  assign("Prod",numeric(10),pos=1)
and then assigning Prod at j-th iteration to Prod[j] but it does not work.

#

Any idea how this can be done? 
Thank you

Comment: You could always just return `list(Prod,Sum)` instead of just `Sum` so you get both values out.

Answer (score 2):

You can add anything you like in the `return()` command. You could return a list `return(list(Sum,Prod))` or a data frame `return(data.frame("In"=j,"Sum"=Sum,"Prod"=Prod))`

I would then convert that list of data.frames into a single data.frame

```
Try2 <- do.call(rbind,Try)
```

Comment: A data.frame is surprisingly costly to produce and manipulate; Sum and Prod are numeric values so why not return a vector `c(Sum=sum(x, y), Prod=prod(x, y))` and coerce to a matrix `matrix(unlist(Try), 2, dimnames=list(NULL, c("Sum", "Prod")))`

Comment: oops, I think there's a `byrow=TRUE` in the coercion to matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe re-think the problem in a more vectorized way, taking advantage of the implied symmetry to represent intermediate values as a matrix and operating on that

```
ni = 10; nj = 20
x = matrix(rnorm(ni * nj), ni)
y = matrix(runif(ni * nj), ni)
sums = colSums(x + y)
prods = apply(x * y, 2, prod)
```

Thinking about the vectorized version is as applicable to whatever your 'real' problem is as it is to the sum / prod example; in practice and when thinking in terms of vectors fails I've never used the environment or concatenation approaches in other answers, but rather the simple solution of returning a list or vector.

Comment: Lol. Too bad the OP's code is a toy problem to help learn about environments and returning values.  Otherwise your answer and comment below would be spot on.

Comment: With respect, there are different definitions of inappropriate enough for a downvote.  I think the original answer I read here qualified.  However, it does get better with each edit, so I am happy to remove my vote.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this before, and it works.  Good for a quick fix, but its kind of sloppy.  The <<- operator assigns outside the function to the global environment.

```
fun2<-function(j){
  x<-rnorm(10)
  y<-runif(10)
  Sum<-sum(x,y)
  Prod[j]<<-prod(x,y)
}
j=1:10
Prod <- numeric(length(j))
Try<-lapply(j,fun2)
Prod
```

Comment: This pattern `c(Prod, prod(x, y))` make n (n - 1) / 2 copies, so scales very poorly -- time your fun2 for j=1:1000, 1:10000, 1:100000 and see that times increase quadratically. Better to 'pre-allocate and fill', along the lines of `Prod = numeric(nj); Prod[[j]] = prod(x, y)` or to vectorize instead.

Comment: You are correct.  My emphasis was focusing on the <<- operator, but might as well do a version that scales linearly.  Thanks, I have made changes.

Comment: I did not down vote you either.  (I did up vote your comment, though.)

Comment: @Martin I down-voted you because I don't think it's an appropriate answer for the question--nothing personal.  You are a great coder and contributor to SO.

Answer (score 0):

thelatemail and JeremyS's solutions are probably what you want.  Using lists is the normal way to pass back a bunch of different data items and I would encourage you to use it.  Quoted here so no one thinks I'm advocating the direct option.

```
return(list(Sum,Prod))
```

Having said that, suppose that you really don't want to pass them back, you could also put them directly in the parent environment from within the function using either `assign` or the superassignment operator.  This practice can be looked down on by functional programming purists, but it does work.  This is basically what you were originally trying to do.

Here's the superassignment version

```
fun2<-function(j)
{
  x<-rnorm(10)
  y<-runif(10)
  Sum<-sum(x,y)
  Prod[j] <<- prod(x,y)
  return(Sum)
}
j=1:10
Prod <- numeric(10)
Try<-lapply(j,fun2)
```

Note that the superassignment searches back for the first environment in which the variable exists and modifies it there.  It's not appropriate for creating new variables above where you are.

And an example version using the environment directly

```
fun2<-function(j,env)
{
  x<-rnorm(10)
  y<-runif(10)
  Sum<-sum(x,y)
  env$Prod[j] <- prod(x,y)
  return(Sum)
}
j=1:10
Prod <- numeric(10)
Try<-lapply(j,fun2,env=parent.frame())
```

Notice that if you had called `parent.frame()` from within the function you would need to go back two frames because `lapply()` creates its own.  This approach has the advantage that you could pass it any environment you want instead of `parent.frame()` and the value would be modified there.  This is the seldom-used R implementation of writeable passing by reference.  It's safer than superassignment because you know where the variable is that is being modified.

Comment: For the environment version I would instead arrange to retrieve the result and to pre-allocate the space for the answer, so `env = new.env(parent=emptyenv()); env$Prod = numeric(10); lapply(j, fun2, env)`; I'd almost never rely on `parent.frame()` or other forms that depend on the call, for the reason that you indicate -- it depends too intricately on the details of the call.

Comment: That's a good suggestion and the only reasonable way to pass by reference in practice.  However, be aware that you would also need to  extract the stuff from `env` after calling `lapply()` or continue to use it within `env`.